# SQL Stratified Sample with minimum per owner for QA

Tags: sql, t-sql, statistics, netezza

I have a SQL population - lets call them alerts. Each alert among various other fields contains an Alert Type (scenario) and an analyst who worked that alert. We are attempting to do a QA sample for various business units and each have their own requirements. Most are straight-forward, but we have one that is tricky. Here are the requirements:

We must sample per the following:

1. Closed Alerts for each alert scenario. Total sample must be at least 60.  Will be stratified proportionately by scenario volume.
2. 5 reviews per analyst or 100% per analyst, whichever is less.
3. All analysts must be in the sample and each scenario must have at least one review.

I'd like to build this all in SQL so SQL can give me back the sample. We have the "5 minimum per analyst or 100% whichever is less" from the entire population, however, we need to get the stratified sample first, but include that 5 per analyst minimum in that process.

My first inclination was to do the stratified sampling, so in order to do that, I determined how many of each scenario was needed to meet those requirements and placed it as a column in the returned data set.

Here is the top of my SQL:

```
SELECT D.*
FROM (
        SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SCENARIO_DESCRIPTION_NM ORDER BY ALERT_ID) AS SEQNUM,
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS TOTAL_COUNT,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SCENARIO_DESCRIPTION_NM) AS SN_COUNT,
        CEIL(SN_COUNT * (SN_COUNT * 1.0 / TOTAL_COUNT)) AS SAMPLE_SIZE
        FROM
```

At the end of the query I have:

```
 WHERE SEQNUM < 500 * (SN_COUNT * 1.0 / TOTAL_COUNT)
```

What this give me are column at the end of the return that tell me the sample size for each scenario:

[image]

However, this just tells me what I need, I want to actually make the query return only the stratified sample BUT it needs to account for every analyst in the population being represented at maximum 5 per or 100% whichever is less (see rule #2 above). It's like combining two sampling methods but I am not sure how to implement this.

Based on the three rules above, how would do this in SQL to get that sample back following those rules? I imagine that this would some two queries for each, but then do some sort of JOIN, but not sure how to approach this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is difficult to understand that you really want. please add a small example that represent your tables with their structure with some data and an example output that you want to get

Comment: Will do, will upload tonight when I get home.